# How to remove Foreign key constraint with if exist check?

Tags: php, sql

I have to remove a foreign key constraint with IF EXIST check. How can I achieve this..

Comment: Explain a bit more, will you?

Answer (score 2):

By using below block you can achive this

> IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys 
>                   WHERE name = 'fk_vMessageType' )
>     BEGIN
>       EXEC ('
>       ALTER TABLE HL7_MessageHierarchy
>        DROP CONSTRAINT fk_vMessageType FOREIGN KEY (vMessageType) 
>              REFERENCES HL7_MessageType(vMessageType)
>        ')
>     END